# Check if CMTime is in CMTimeRange

Tags: ios, swift, range, avfoundation, cmtime

I'm trying to understand what is the correct way to check if `CMTime` is in range. Example:

let's assume we have a video, with a duration of 20 seconds. We split this video into two `CMTimeRange`.

- from 0 seconds to 10
- from 10 seconds to 20

Now, for any given `CMTime` (for example, the video progress). How can I determine in which `CMTimeRange` a `CMTime` Exists?

Comment: What about `if range.containsTime(time)` ?

Comment: @MartinR I have no idea how I didn't find this method before. Lol. Thank you Martin. Can you please post an answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CMTimeRange` has a

```
func containsTime(_ time: CMTime) -> Bool
```

method, so you can simply check

```
if range.containsTime(time) {
    // ...
}
```

*Remark:* The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/1462775-cmtimerangecontainstime)  seems to be outdated, the global
function `CMTimeRangeContainsTime()` is imported as a member function
to Swift.

Comment: Marin R. I know it's it's off topic. But any chance you know if there is a convenient method for Splitting CMTimeRange into multiple chunks?

Comment: @RoiMulia: I have no idea. Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/cmtimerange-qts to check if there is anything convenient.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to figure it out. Have a great day Martin!

Comment: Hey Martin, I got stuck. I've published a new questions regards this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787869/split-cmtimerange-into-multiple-cmtimerange-chunks I'm sure you are busy, but just in case you have some good direction :) Thank you either way!