# Split CMTimeRange into multiple CMTimeRange chunks

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, chunks, cmtime

Lets assume I have a `CMTimeRange` constructed from `start time` zero, and 
 `duration` of 40 seconds.

I want to split this `CMTimeRange` into multiple chunks by a **X** seconds divider. So the `total duration` of the chunks will be the same `duration` as the original duration, and each `startTime` will reflect the `endTime` of of the previous chunk. The last chunk will be the **modulus** of the left over seconds.

For example, for video of **40** seconds, and divider of **15** seconds per chunk:

1. First `CMTimeRange` - start time: 0, duration: 15 seconds.
2. Second `CMTimeRange` - start time: 15, duration: 15 seconds.
3. Third `CMTimeRange` - start time: 30, duration: 10 seconds. `(left overs)`

*What I've tried:*

I tried using `CMTimeSubtract` on the total duration and use the result again, in recursive way untill the CMTime in invalid, But it doesn't seems to work.

**Any help will be highly appreciated.**

**Best Regards, Roi**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting at `range.start`, create ranges of the given length
until `range.end` is reached:

```
func splitIntoChunks(range: CMTimeRange, length: CMTime) -> [CMTimeRange] {

    var chunks: [CMTimeRange] = []
    var from = range.start
    while from < range.end {
        chunks.append(CMTimeRange(start: from, duration: length).intersection(range))
        from = from + length
    }

    return chunks
}
```

`intersection` is used here to prune the last chunk to the original range.

Alternative solution:

```
func splitIntoChunks(range: CMTimeRange, length: CMTime) -> [CMTimeRange] {

    return stride(from: range.start.seconds, to: range.end.seconds, by: length.seconds).map {
        CMTimeRange(start: CMTime(seconds: $0, preferredTimescale: length.timescale), duration: length)
            .intersection(range)
    }

}
```

With a custom extension to make `CMTime` adopt the [`Strideable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/strideable)
protocol

```
extension CMTime: Strideable {
    public func distance(to other: CMTime) -> TimeInterval {
        return other - self
    }

    public func advanced(by n: TimeInterval) -> CMTime {
        return self + n
    }
}
```

this can be further simplified to

```
func splitIntoChunks(range: CMTimeRange, length: CMTime) -> [CMTimeRange] {

    return stride(from: range.start, to: range.end, by: length.seconds).map {
        CMTimeRange(start: $0, duration: length) .intersection(range)
    }
}
```

In any case, you'll might want to add a check

```
precondition(length.seconds > 0, "length must be positive")
```

to your function, in order to detect invalid calls during development.

Comment: Both of them works simply perfect! I have to admit that even with one or two extra days, the solution I would come up with would be far less clean. Thank you again Martin. Super grateful!

Answer (score 0):

I too needed to stride `CMTime`, to deal with `AVCaptureDevice` exposure durations & showing these to users.

Turns out Martin's answer doesn't work anymore with the changes in Swift 4.x / XCode 10. Here's my version of `CMTime` conformance to `Strideable`:

```
extension CMTime: Strideable {
    public func distance(to other: CMTime) -> TimeInterval {
        return TimeInterval((Double(other.value) / Double(other.timescale)) - (Double(self.value) /  Double(self.timescale)))
    }

    public func advanced(by n: TimeInterval) -> CMTime {
        var retval = self
        retval.value += CMTimeValue(n * TimeInterval(self.timescale))
        return retval
    }
}
```

I derped with it in a playground and it seems to work.